# How to Fetch date from DateTime Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

How to Fetch date from `DateTime` Object?

**Output is:**

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [instrument_token] => 16796674 
        [exchange_token] => 65612 
        [tradingsymbol] => DABUR18MAR445CE 
        [name] => 
        [last_price] => 0.05 
        [expiry] => DateTime Object ( 
            [date] => 2018-03-28 00:00:00.000000 
            [timezone_type] => 3 
            [timezone] => asia/kolkata 
        ) 
        [strike] => 445 
        [tick_size] => 0.05 
        [lot_size] => 2500 
        [instrument_type] => CE 
        [segment] => NFO-OPT 
        [exchange] => NFO 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime Object` here is a string representation of the object (see [`__toString()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)).

You could use [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get a string as you want :

```
$date_str = $array[0]->expiry->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```